# Como leer un child de un JSON con C#

Tags: c#, json, unity

Recibo como respuesta de una API el siguiente `string`:

```
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Este `string` contiene:

```
{"success":{"username":"62b7562c90c7f7543b0eabea00359f3"}}
```

Quiero obtener el usuario dentro de una variable para poder loguearme con la API.

Mi problema es acceder hasta ese dato, he probado esto:

```
dynamic o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);
Debug.Log(o[0]["success"][0].username);
```

Todo está escrito en un script de Unity, C#.
Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Sería `o["success"]["username"].ToString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No recomiendo que uses dynamic sino que deserialices a una estructura, puedes ayudarte con

> http://json2csharp.com/

entonces obtienes las clases

```
public class Success
{
    public string username { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Success success { get; set; }
}
```

Para deserializar

```
RootObject o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseFromServer);
Debug.Log(o.success.username);
```

de esta forma te aseguras que el json que obtienes respecta la estructura que queires conseguir

Comment: Esta es efectivamente la mejor opción. Solo recordar que Visual Studio tiene su propia herramienta para crear las clases a partir de un json, no es necesario usar un servicio externo.

Comment: Cuando lo lanzo me notifica que no puede deserializarlo, he buscado en la red pero no encuentro nada que me solucione.

Gracias por tu mensaje.
JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'RootObject' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: pero estas seguro que el json que recibes tiene esa estructura que has mencionado? si inspeccionas el string que obtienes puedes validarlo, porque quizas el `success` no se esta incluyendo y es otra la estructura

Comment: Tengo la duda de si está incluyendo este carácter: [ ]

[{"success":{"username":"b024c5b50491fe91bb597c9e1a0687b"}}]

La consola de Unity me devuelve eso cuando imprimo el string responsefromserver. ¿Puede ser esto el causante del error?

Comment: esa estructura es distinta, cuando aparecen los `[]` esos indica un array, igual es raro qe tengas uno vacio sin contenido, pero el que esta con el success dentro ese es otro item y la estructura de la clase es diferente, usa la url json2csharp que mencione y veras como la class generadas cambian

Comment: Finalmente he eliminado esos caracteres con las siguientes líneas de código:  char[] MyChar = { '[', ']' }; string respuesta = responseFromServer.Trim(MyChar); Y junto a tus indicaciones lo he resuelto. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo.