# ¿Cómo leer el valor de varios childs en un JSON con C#?

Tags: c#, json, unity

Deseo leer varios datos del siguiente JSON:
El JSON es mucho más largo, es una respuesta de la API de Philips Hue a un GET que le solicita el listado de bombillas. Yo sólo quiero valores del primer elemento del JSON SIN especificar cuál es el primero, esto podría variar.

```
{ 
   "1":{ 
      "modelid":"LCT001",
      "name":"Hue Lamp 1",
      "swversion":"65003148",
      "state":{ 
         "xy":[ 
            0,
            0
         ],
         "ct":0,
         "alert":"none",
         "sat":254,
         "effect":"none",
         "bri":254,
         "hue":4444,
         "colormode":"hs",
         "reachable":true,
         "on":true
      },
      "type":"Extended color light",
      "pointsymbol":{ 
         "1":"none",
         "2":"none",
         "3":"none",
         "4":"none",
         "5":"none",
         "6":"none",
         "7":"none",
         "8":"none"
      },
      "uniqueid":"00:17:88:01:00:d4:12:08-0a"
   }
}
```

Yo estoy solicitando los datos hasta un punto en concreto.

```
string respuesta = webRequest.downloadHandler.text;
JObject root = JObject.Parse(respuesta);
JProperty property = (JProperty)root.First;
Debug.Log(property.Value["state"]);
```

Esto me devuelve como respuesta:

```
{
  "xy": [
    0,
    0
  ],
  "ct": 0,
  "alert": "none",
  "sat": 254,
  "effect": "none",
  "bri": 254,
  "hue": 4444,
  "colormode": "hs",
  "reachable": true,
  "on": true
}
```

Pero por ejemplo, ¿Existe alguna forma de acceder directo a el elemento "on"?
Gracias a todos.

Comment: Tal vez [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329952/como-leer-un-child-de-un-json-con-c/329958#329958) te sea de ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basándome en tu ejemplo del ***`json`*** que dejas y la forma en como lo manipulas puede hacer lo siguiente para obtener el valor de ***`on`***:

```
JObject root = JObject.Parse(respuesta);
JProperty property = (JProperty)root.First;
Debug.Log(property.Value["state"]["on"]);
```

Otra forma de hacerlo, por si necesitas tener el objeto o valor de `on` por separado:

```
JObject root = JObject.Parse(respuesta);
JProperty property = (JProperty)root.First;
Debug.Log(property.Value["state"]);

JToken tokenOn = property.Value["state"]["on"];
Debug.Log(tokenOn);
```

Si revisas la documentación te darás cuenta que el indexador `property.Value["state"]` que utilizas ya te devuelve un `JToken` por lo tanto puedes volver a utilizar el indexador del token devuelto para obtener el valor de `on`.

> Recuerda siempre validar si las propiedades o valores que buscas son nulos.

Answer (score 0):

primero debes crear el modelo del json en una clase, luego deserializar el objeto y podes usar la propiedad que desees.
Puedes usar http://json.parser.online.fr/ para pegar el json y crear el modelo de manera mas rápida.

Luego debes deserializar el objetivo

//utiliza la libreria 
    using Newtownsoft.Json;

//utiliza esta linea en tu metodo.

```
var resultado = JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<MiClase>>(json);
```

//la variable json, es un string que lees del servicio.
//Luego puedes recorrer con un foreach

```
 foreach (var item in resultado )
 {
     item.on
 }
```